# How to get values of Summatory Liouville function from Mertens function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

All:

For Liouville function λ(n), we can define summatory Liouville as the accumulated sum of of λ(n). Mertens function is the accumulated sum of Mobius function.

Is there any ways to get the value summatory Liouville function from Mertens function ?

The reason I asked this question is that, it seems there are some efficient algorithms to calculate Mertens function. I just want to know how to adopt those similar algorithms to calculate summatory Liouville function.

My personal goal is to find the counter example of  Pólya conjecture  as in:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function
by calculating summatory Liouville for some larger number.

Comment: For the purposes of calculation, it will be far faster to adapt the Mertens-function algorithm so that it computes the Liouville summatory function, rather than trying to derive the Liouville summatory function from the output of the Mertens summatory function. (By the way, the name is [Mertens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Mertens), not Merten.)

Comment: $\frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)} = \zeta(2s) \ \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ hence $s \int_1^\infty L(x) x^{-s-1}dx = \frac{\zeta(2s)}{s\zeta(s)} = \zeta(2s) \ \frac{1}{s\zeta(s)} = \zeta(2s) s \int_1^\infty M(x) x^{-s-1}dx$ $ = s \int_1^\infty (\sum_n M(x/ n^2 ) ) x^{-s-1}dx$ so that $$L(x)= \sum_n M(x/n^2)$$

Comment: and I don't think you'll find the value of $M(x)$ for $x = 906150257$ it is too large for computing on normal computers

Comment: Calculate Mertens function for x = 906150257 is not difficult. Because there are many algorithm to calculate Mertens function.

Comment: @david : $\mathcal{O}(x^{0.7})$ in time AND memory means with $x = 10^9$ that you'll need $\mathcal{O}(10^{6.3})$ operations in time AND memory, try yourself on your computer (I hope for you the $\mathcal{O}$ constant is not too big :D )

Comment: @user1952009, thank you for answer my question and provide formula. I did implement your formula. On my four year old laptop, it takes 26 seconds to calculate Mertens function for x = 906316571 , and it takes 95 seconds to calculate Summatory Liouville function for x =  906316571, and I got value 829 which is stated on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function

Comment: great, so I guess you had access to the $O(x^{0.7})$ algorithm, can you share a link with your code ? (I use some $O(x)$ algorithms that I do myself, for studying $M(x)$ in some ranges, so I extrapolated $10^9$ was too large with any algorithms, obviously I was wrong)

Comment: My code is based on algorithm in: Computing the Summation of the M¨obius Function, Marc Del´eglise and Jo¨el Rivat

Answer (score 3):

One can show that
\[\sum_{d \mid n} \lambda(d) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $d$ is a perfect square,} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}\]
Indeed, $\lambda(n)$ is multiplicative, so one only needs to check this on prime powers, and this is easy.

Via Möbius inversion, it therefore follows that
\[\lambda(n) = \sum_{d^2 m = n} \mu(m),\]
and so
\[L(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \lambda(n) = \sum_{d^2 m \leq x} \mu(m) = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \sum_{m \leq x/d^2} \mu(m) = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} M\left(\frac{x}{d^2}\right).\]

This is the same answer that user1952009 got, but directly using Möbius inversion instead of Mellin transforms and Dirichlet series.

(Note that these are essentially the same, however; one can think of Dirichlet series as being the generating function of multiplicative functions, and multiplication of Dirichlet series is the same as Dirichlet convolution. Mellin transforms then relate Dirichlet series to summatory functions.)

Similarly, one can show that
\[\mu(n) = \sum_{d^2 m = n} \mu(d) \lambda(m),\]
and so
\[M(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = \sum_{d^2 m \leq x} \mu(d) \lambda(m) = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \mu(d) \sum_{m \leq x/d^2} \lambda(m) = \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \mu(d) L\left(\frac{x}{d^2}\right).\]

All this being said, there are faster ways to compute the summatory function of the Liouville function. For example, [this paper of R. Sherman Lehman](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1960-14-072/S0025-5718-1960-0120198-5/) gives more complicated recursive formulae that allowed him to compute values of $L(x)$ reasonably quickly by the standards of 1960. More recently, work of [Borwein, Ferguson, and Mossinghoff](http://academics.davidson.edu/math/mossinghoff/LiouvilleSums2_BFM.pdf) and [Mossinghoff and Trudgian](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1446788712000201) involve even faster algorithms to compute $L(x)$.